# My R in library is red but I can build and run app normally

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I use  `compile project(':pickphotos')`  to include a library named pickphotos.

The R in pickphotos is red though I have me.crosswall.photo.pick.R.I can build and run the app normally.

[image]

When I use Alt+Enter , it shows some solution:

[image]

When I use Move 'R' in pickphotos, it shows some R:

[image]

But if I pick me.crosswall.photo.pick.R,I will get repeat R error in my next build.

Below is the build.gradle of pickphotos:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

I can also find it app/build/generated/source/r:

[image]

There is no Mark as item in menu in Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: sometimes this happen when there is error in xml files
check that first then clean the project

Comment: i think, you should mark the generated-source folder as generated sources in the Android Studio.

Comment: @Delta7 I clean project and delete build folder serval times.

Comment: @NagyVilmos How can I mark it?

Comment: I'd search for it in File -> Project Structure menu.

Comment: There is no place to mark in Project Structure.

Comment: Right-click on the folder and 'Mark Directory As..' ? At least that's how one does it in IntelliJ.

Comment: Delete generated files and clean

Comment: I have tried to delete build folder of app and clean.I will try to delete build folder of pickphotos.

Comment: "But if I pick me.crosswall.photo.pick.R,I will get repeat R error in my next build." Please post the **exact** error message. Summarizing loses information that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resloved it.

Just Make Project.

R is created when Make Project.

I think when we Run Project or Build Project,Android Studio doesn't Make Project for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Going to Build > Rebuild Project and/or Clean Project seems to be the goto first attempt at fixing any mindboggling red errors. Better to do that then spend 45 minutes staring at code trying to figure out what's wrong when the answer turns out to be 'nothing'...